# Error in MVC Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have Linq query in MVC

```cs
obj_CCM.TeamName = (from c in db.Team_Master
                    where c.Id != TeamId
                    select new TypeTeam
                    {
                        TeamID = c.Id,
                        TeamName = c.TeamName
                    }
                   ).ToList();

Session["TeamId"] = obj_CCM.TeamName.Count > 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(obj_CCM.TeamName[0].TeamID) : -1;
```

I facing below error :

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: `obj_CCM.TeamName` Is this a typo? I guess it should be `obj_CCM.TypeTeam`

Comment: So the error is telling you that the TeamId (so db.Team_Master.Id) is null. Does that match what the database has stored?

Comment: It could also be `obj_CCM.TeamName[0].TeamID` you should make sure they have a value before returning it using `.HasValue`

Answer (score 0):

I guess issue is at this line:

```
TeamID = c.Id
```

In your `Team_Master` table, the `Id` column must be Nullable so it is returning null but property `TeamID` in `TypeTeam` is defined as `int` and can't hold null values. So you need to either disallow your Id column in database to accept null values or make the `TeamID` property as nullable of integer.

```
public int? TeamID{ get; set; }
```

Also, as a side note, your query is returning `List<TypeTeam>` but you are storing that in `obj_CCM.TeamName`, either this is a typo or you may have defined `TeamName` of type `List<TypeTeam>`.

Comment: yes..I have TeamName of type List<TypeTeam>. id in Team Master is not nullable.

Comment: @samarkadam - Ohk, so is it working for u? Have you tried changing the datatype of `TeamID` to `int?`

Answer (score 0):

Check first, if

```
Session["TeamId"] != null
```

and then do the converting